# WindowsFormsHost in WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

Is it possible to place `WindowsFormsHost` in `WPF` UserControl, if so how pls.

I have already used the same control on a WPF Window, which works fine, but it does not show up on WPF `UserControl`.

Comment: `WindowsFormsHost` is used to, as its name suggests, host a `WindowsForms` control in a `WPF` window, what have you put inside the `WindowsFormsHost` container?

Comment: I placed a Panel in the WindowsFormsHost  on the WPF WIndow, it shows correctly, but when i pace the same control on wpf UserControl the WindowsFormsHost  does not show at all at run time, i was just wondering if WindowsFormsHost  can be used on a wpf UserControl.

Comment: Sure it can. Please provide a minimal [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when asking a question on SO.